# Qualitative determination of the presence of cations

Tags: analytical-chemistry, books

In "Introduction to Analytical Chemistry" I have been asked to propose various tests and chemical methods to determine whether a sample contains a series of metallic cations.

These metallic cations are as follows: $\ce{Cu^{2+}}$, $\ce{Pt^{2+}}$, $\ce{Pt^{4+}}$, $\ce{Hg^{+}}$, $\ce{Fe^{3+}}$.

Obviously, I'm not asking you to do the exercise for me. But, if it is possible, I would like to be indicated some book or manual, if it is possible that it is in Internet, to be able to solve it correctly. Also, I hope they can give some indication of how they would solve it.

Comment: The red Jander-Blasius is your friend.

Comment: Please consult Vogel, A Textbook of Qualitative Inorganic Analysis. It is one of the classics in the field. Also think of atomic emission spectroscopy. Search these keywords and you would find an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can recognize Fe(III) by adding some thiocyanate ion to the solution, which must be at least a little acidic. If it contains Fe(III) ions, it will turn dark red. This test is specific to iron. 
Copper(II) ion can be recognized by adding some potassium iodide to its solution, which must be at lest a little bit acidic. A brown precipitate should appear which is made of a mixture of copper(I) iodide and iodine I2. If you add an equal volume of an alcane like cyclohexane and stir, the iodine I2 will pass into the organic phase which yields a purple solution. 
I don't know the properties of Pt ions.
Mercury(I)+ ion may be recognized by adding some HCl. It will produce a white precipitate of Hg2Cl2. The only ion producing the same precipitate is the silver ion Ag+.